# Create new column with conditions SQL access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

My question is very simple and even though I've tried different SQL codes, none has been successful.

I have an Access database with a table called `Dates`. `Dates` contains 8 columns, among them there are these 5: `EmployeesName`, `Gender`, `Profession`, `InitialDate`, and `FinalDate`.

How I can create a query Access consult showing all the 8 columns of the table `Dates` where `Gender` = `M` (first condition), and a new column that is the difference in datetime between `InitialDate` and `FinalDate` called `Difference`, the output must be grouped by `Profession` and then in alphabetic order for `EmployeesName`? I've used the suggested query of one member shown below but Access shows me the following message: "Inquiry does not include the specified expression "EmployesName" as part of an added function":

```
SELECT EmployeesName, Gender, Profession, [Initial date], [Final Date], [Final Date] - [Initial Date] AS [Difference] 
FROM Dates 
WHERE Gender = 'M'
GROUP BY Profession 
ORDER BY 'EmployeesName';
```

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING AT US?

Comment: Do you have a version of MS Office which includes Access so that you can use the Access query designer to create and test your query?

Comment: Yes HansUp. I've modified my question so that anyone who knows can see my query which is not working.

Comment: Thanks HansUp. Now I have refreshed it.

Comment: Your query is not using any aggregate functions so I don't understand why you're using `GROUP BY`.  What do you need that this query does not give you? `SELECT EmployeesName, Gender, Profession, [Initial date], [Final Date], [Final Date] - [Initial Date] AS [Difference] FROM Dates WHERE Gender = 'M' ORDER BY Profession, EmployeesName;`

Comment: You told us the table includes a field named `EmployeesName`, but your `SELECT` refers to `EmployesName` instead.  You need to get such details correct if you want an Access query to work properly.  If you use the query designer to build the query as I suggested, it can help you avoid mis-spelled field names.

Comment: Thank you very much HansUp. Group By function was wrongly used in the query. I used your command lines with "Profession" order and then "EmployesName" and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Good.  Please submit an answer with the `SELECT` statement which works for you and accept that answer later when the system allows you to do so.

Comment: OK. I'll first change the columns to "EmployeesName" and then I'll add the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT EmployeesName, Gender, Profession, [Initial date], [Final Date], [Final Date] - [Initial Date] AS [Difference] 
FROM Dates 
WHERE Gender = 'M'
ORDER BY 'Profession', 'EmployeesName';